# How to Modify Logging Fields on Pino express Log

Tags: express, logging

I am using express-pino-logger for logging system. It is all working fine but it is logging lot of unwanted data all Request data. So how can i restrict specific Fields while logging.

```
var expressPino = require('express-pino-logger')({ prettyPrint: { colorize: true } });
app.use(pino);
app.get('/test',function(req, res) {
req.log.info("Something");
});
```

Above Code Logging Lot of Unwanted Result like below Json.

```
{"level":30,"time":1559044530446,"pid":2462,"hostname":"PATRALTOP-46","prettyPrint":{"colorize":true},"req":{"id":10,"method":"GET","url":"/user/profile","headers":{"host":"localhost:3011","connection":"keep-alive","user-agent":"Mozilla36","accept":"*/*","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9,ta;q=0.8","cookie":"menubShQ","if-none-match":"W2b7bpE08jO8lVNTEV/tg9OIRMd3fI"},"remoteAddress":"::1","remotePort":58260},"res":{"statusCode":304,"headers":{"x-powered-by":"Express","etag":"W2b7b-OpE08jO8lVNTEV/tg9OIRMd3fI"}},"responseTime":106,"msg":"something","v":1}
```

So How can we specify or remove fields while logging.

Answer (score 3):

Set `base: undefined` in the options you are passing to the Pino instance. It will remove `pid` and `hostname` from each log.

There are more options available to manipulate the logs.
For more details checkout the API specs:
https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/HEAD/docs/api.md#base-object

Answer (score -2):

Latest version supports `redact` feature

https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/master/docs/redaction.md#redaction

Comment: Answer on top suits better the purpose since the question is specifically about the base fields.

Comment: Beautiful answer! `Base: undefined` looks very ugly.